# Makeidx, Subentries and dashes

Tags: punctuation, indexing

The following is the type of code I made.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

... something\index{Lois!Lane} ...

\printindex
\end{document}
```

I'd like an index with a dash before any subentry (obviously, under the respectively entry)

```
Marco, Ill, 1
Lois,
 -  Lane, 1 
 -  John, 1
```

How can I do anything like this?
What if a want with a comma after every dash? Like this

```
Marco, Ill, 1
Lois,
 -  , Lane, 1 
 -  , John, 1
```

**EDIT**

If it is not possible to perfectly allign the dash with makeidx, what about Xindy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This requires the `makeindex style file` to be changed/extended.

For example, a `dashindex.ist` can be defined to be

```
item_1  "\n \\subitem -- , "
item_x1 "\n \\subitem -- , "
```

saying, that the sub levels should be preceeded by a dash and a comma.

> Calling flow:
>
> `pdflatex foo`
>
> `makeindex -s dashindex.ist foo`
>
> `pdflatex foo`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

... somethex\index{Lois!Lane} ...

\index{Gandalf!The Grey}
\index{Gandalf!Stormcrow}
\index{Gandalf!Mithrandir}%
\index{Lois!John}
\index{Lois!Clark}

\printindex


\end{document}
```

[image]

### A direct manipulation of `\subitem`

This cures the indentation problem -- in this case, no special `.ist` file is needed. I've set the subitem indent to `5pt`, but this could be changed to basically any length value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\newlength{\subitemindent}
\setlength{\subitemindent}{5pt}
\makeindex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\subitem}{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{\subitemindent} -- , }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

... somethex\index{Lois!Lane} ...

\index{Gandalf!The Grey}
\index{Gandalf!Stormcrow}
\index{Gandalf!Mithrandir}%
\index{Lois!John}
\index{Lois!Clark}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it not possible to have the dash exactly (namely centered) under the first entry?

Comment: @W4cc0: I don't know, I'll have look later on, ok?

Comment: Yes, do not worry. I was just asking because with short words it happens that the dash is under the numbers and that is awful.

Comment: @W4cc0: It could be possible using `xindy` instead of `makeindex`...

Comment: If it is impossible to do with makeidx I'll try with xindy.

Comment: @W4cc0: I managed it by manipulation of the `subitem` entry, the index style file is not needed in this case

Comment: I still thank you Christian. I know I'm a pain in the neck, but in this way the commas are not alligned... I woud like to have a dash in the center under the first entry then the first commas alligned to the upper commas.

Comment: I thought about it and I think that this is the best one can possibly do (without unbelievable manipulations). So thanks for all!

Comment: @W4cc0: Well, it might be possible anyway, but at the moment I am not sure how to align those entries. Although you already accepted it, I will try to improve my solution

Comment: In the middle time I've installed xindy. So now I'm curious. How this can be accomplished by xindy? What is the kind of .xdy file that one have to do?