# Index with dashes to show levels

Tags: indexing, makeindex

A LaTeX `makeindex` style with dashes to indicate subitems and subsubitems is desired. The posting [Makeidx, Subentries and dashes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211143/makeidx-subentries-and-dashes) here looked like the ticket. With the suggested additions, and a couple from elsewhere, here is the modified `.ist`

```
preamble "\\begin{theindex}\\thispagestyle{empty}\n"
quote '+'
headings_flag 1
heading_suffix ""
item_1  "\n \\subitem --- "
item_x1 "\n \\subitem --- "
item_2  "\n \\subsubitem --- --- "
item_x2 "\n \\subsubitem --- --- "
delim_0 ": "
delim_1 ": "
delim_2 ": "
delim_r "-"
suffix_2p "\\,f."
suffix_3p "\\,ff."
```

The following LaTeX MWE was tested with the style file above (the idxlayout package is used to kill the indents and get a multicolumn index)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[subindent=0pt,subsubindent=0pt, totoc=true]{idxlayout}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

ParentA\index{ParentA}, SubAA\index{ParentA!SubAA}, SubAB\index{ParentA!SubAB}, SubAC\index{ParentA!SubAC}

ParentB\index{ParentB}, SubBA\index{ParentB!SubBA}, SubsubBAA\index{ParentB!SubBA!SubsubBAA}, SubsubBAB\index{ParentB!SubBA!SubsubBAB}, SubBB\index{ParentB!SubBB}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The problem is that, in the output, the first subitem in a list of subitems *does not get* the preceding dash(es)

[image: undesired index format]

even though the second, third, etc. do. The desired index output is

[image: desired index format]

The undesired output only seems to happen when the parent item is itself indexed in the document (and so gets a page number in the index). How may I achieve the desired index format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit more research, and I found the answer. Two *more* lines need to be added to the `.ist` file, namely

```
item_01 "\n \\subitem --- "
item_12 "\n \\subsubitem --- --- "
```

where, for example `item_01` is the

`Command to be inserted between a level 0 item and a level 1 item.`

The command `item_x1` is the

`Command to be inserted between a level 0 item and a level 1 item, where the level 0 item does not have associated page numbers.`

There is a similar distinction between `item_12` and `item_x2`. Adding the two commands to the `.ist` file gives the desired effect, whether the parent index item has a page number or not.

The quoted descriptions come from the Overleaf web site, at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Indices.